# Android no persistence (null Bundle) in Fragment

Tags: android, persistence, bundle, android-fragments, android-preferences

I just started to develop for Android platform. For the application I am working on, I am using an activity with the following .xml file in order to manage the application properties.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="fr.berard.preference.ManagePreferenceActivity$PreferenceMenuFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="80"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When the user select an element from PreferenceMenuFragment, the details fragment is loaded by the following lines:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
PreferenceFragment pdf = new CustomPreferenceFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.details, pdf);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);       
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The activity works fine, the problem is comes from the persistance. I implemented onSaveInstanceState() in the class extanding PreferenceFragment.

```
public final String WRONG_CARD_KEY = "wrong_card_value";

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(WRONG_CARD_KEY)) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), " loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    savedInstanceState.putString(WRONG_CARD_KEY, "test");
    Toast.makeText(this.getActivity()," saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

When when I press the home button, the onSaveInstanceState() method is called. But when I go back to the PreferenceFragment, onActivityCreated() is called but the bundle is still null.
I can't explain why the informations i put in onSaveInstanceState are not saved. Maybe it I made a mistake while implementing my Fragment, maybe it is comming from the way I start it in the main activity.
I found some posts with the same problem with ListFragment but without answer.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `onSaveInstanceState` call is more of a pre-emptive call in case the fragment/activity is subsequently destroyed (say by the OS reclaiming memory) and needs to be restored by the system. As your fragment isn't being destroyed and recreated it doesn't need to restore itself from the saved state.

Comment: My problem is when i change manually a value in the PreferenceFragment (for example adding a summary to a preference), when I go back to the preferences, the summary disappear.

Comment: Haven't used a PreferenceFragment but can you save the state in instance data (say ensuring up-to-date) in onDestroyView and then restoring your fragment from the saved state in onCreateView...